# Inject class in body when particular page template is used

Tags: php, functions, pages, page-template

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

In header.php I have written the above code.

But I want when this page template is in use:

```
page-customer.php
```

then

```
body_customer
```

class should go above. Is this possible through some hook?

Comment: Just searching "body_class hook" would've led you to this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Comment: I pasted the wrong link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/

Comment: Yes. When the answer to your question is a 3-word Google search away, the question "does not show any research effort", which is what the downvote arrow says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a filter for that and it's called... `body_class` ;) 
This should work for your case:

```
function add_my_custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-customer.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'body_customer';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_my_custom_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

if you wanna add class based on page ID (as you've mentioned in comments), you can change the logic inside the function and add class only when particular page is queried, let's say your page ID is 3:

```
if ( 3 === get_the_ID() ){
     $classes[] = 'your_additional_class';
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was interested in adding based on page template only. Thanks for the help.